# Matlab onclick callback to execute function

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback

I want Matlab to execute a function that takes the specific point I clicked on as an input, so for example, if I plot

```
plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2))
scatter(xy(:,1),xy(:,2))
```

and then click on a specific point (see figure), it will execute a callback function whose inputs are not only the x,y coordinate of that point but also its index value (ie its the 4th row of variable xy)

Thanks alot!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by using the `ButtonDownFcn` property of `Scatter` objects.

In the main script:

```
% --- Define your data
N = 10;
x = rand(N,1);
y = rand(N,1);

% --- Plot and define the callback
h = scatter(x, y, 'bo');
set(h, 'ButtonDownFcn', @myfun);
```

and in the function `myfun`:

```
function myfun(h, e)

% --- Get coordinates
x = get(h, 'XData');
y = get(h, 'YData');

% --- Get index of the clicked point
[~, i] = min((e.IntersectionPoint(1)-x).^2 + (e.IntersectionPoint(2)-y).^2);

% --- Do something
hold on
switch e.Button
    case 1, col = 'r';
    case 2, col = 'g';
    case 3, col = 'b';
end
plot(x(i), y(i), '.', 'color', col);
```

`i` is the index of the clicked point, so `x(i)` and `y(i)` are the coordinates of the clicked point.

Amazingly enough, the mouse button which performed the action is stored in `e.Button`:

- 1: left click
- 2: middle click
- 3: right click

so you can play around with that too. Here is the result:

[image]

Best,